# iPhone is ignoring body margin on Responsive Layout

Tags: android, iphone, css, ios, responsive-design

We have an issue with our responsive design. We use this style for mobile devices on our responsive theme:

```
body {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    max-width: 90%;
}
```

Below you can see a difference between iOS Broswer and Chrome:

[image]

Comment: Tried it. I am getting the same thing.

Comment: Yes I did. It worked with percentages: body {
 margin-left: 5%;
 margin-right: 5%;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 max-width: 90%;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It worked with percentages:

`body { margin-left: 5%; margin-right: 5%; overflow-x: hidden; max-width: 90%; margin: 0 auto; }`

Comment: I just tried your first code (with px margin), it worked. So your problem must be in another part of your code.

Answer (score 0):

It does not make sense to apply margin to your body, as it is the outermost element. Instead your should use a padding.

Comment: Used this: 

body {
 padding-left: 10px;
 padding-right: 10px;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 max-width: 90%;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

and I am getting the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

According to this ancient blog post [Body padding and margin](http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/body/), different browsers will handle margin and padding on the body element in different ways.  It wouldn't surprise me if this type of difference is still occurring today.